# Problems with Assets 2.1.3 when upgrading - throws db error

Tags: assets

I'm trying to upgrade to version 2.1.3 of Assets but during the update process it throws the following error:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1265

Data truncated for column 'folder_id' at row 330

ALTER TABLE exp_assets_files MODIFY COLUMN `folder_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AFTER `file_id`

Filename: third_party/assets/upd.assets.php

Line Number: 549

---

Once this happens I have to restore the db to get the site running again. Is there a fix for this?

I am using EE2.6.1, PHP 5.4.14 and MySQL 5

Thanks,
Dave.

Comment: Probably best you email support@pixelandtonic.com directly about this.

Comment: I have been trying to update our Assets from 1.1.5 to 2.1.4 and received a similar error. I'm working with PT support to try and resolve it, but did you ever get it resolved and if so, what was the fix?

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up and fix from P&T support... 'about to be' released v2.2.5 solved the issue.

> the most common error for this is because some of the files that are
>   registered for Assets fields are missing and during the update to
>   Assets 2.x, Assets does not know where in folder structure the file
>   belongs, so it gets a folder_id of NULL. After that, there's a
>   migration that sets the folder_id column to NOT NULL, so that produces
>   the error you're having about data being truncated.
>
> Then, when you run it again, some tables have been modified already,
>   but Assets begins the process anew and that produces the second error
>   :)
>
> Try the attached 2.2.5 version which is not yet released - it should
>   work for you. You will have to revert the DB to the state it was
>   before the failed update, though.