# Database error when updating Assets 1.1.4 to latest (2.2.4)

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

**EE v2.4** but also tried updating first to EE 2.8 with same results as per below.

Christiaan

**When trying to update I receive the following:**

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1265

Data truncated for column 'folder_id' at row 2

ALTER TABLE exp_assets_files MODIFY COLUMN `folder_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AFTER `file_id`

Filename: /Library/WebServer/sites/disegno/_ee/_third_party/assets/upd.assets.php

Line Number: 551
```

**And then if I try again I get the following:**

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'disegno_com_au.exp_assets_entries' doesn't exist

SHOW COLUMNS FROM `exp_assets_entries` LIKE "var_id"

Filename: /Library/WebServer/sites/disegno/_ee/_third_party/assets/upd.assets.php

Line Number: 341
```

Comment: There's a duplicate thread (http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/problems-with-assets-2-1-3-when-upgrading-throws-db-error) with the same problem in which it was advised you contact Pixel and Tonic directly (support@pixelandtonic.com). Nobody ever replied with the answer on that thread so if you could work with P&T to resolve this could you respond with an answer? Good luck!

Comment: I get the same error, trying to upgrade to Assets 2.5. Any ideas?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up and fix from P&T support... 'about to be' released v2.2.5 solved the issue.

> the most common error for this is because some of the files that are
>   registered for Assets fields are missing and during the update to
>   Assets 2.x, Assets does not know where in folder structure the file
>   belongs, so it gets a folder_id of NULL. After that, there's a
>   migration that sets the folder_id column to NOT NULL, so that produces
>   the error you're having about data being truncated.
>
> Then, when you run it again, some tables have been modified already,
>   but Assets begins the process anew and that produces the second error
>   :)
>
> Try the attached 2.2.5 version which is not yet released - it should
>   work for you. You will have to revert the DB to the state it was
>   before the failed update, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed this issue, I've had it on a couple of different sites.

Basically it's because of corrupted data in the exp_assets or the exp_assets_files table.

If you're on an earlier version of Assets you'll only have the exp_assets table.

Check the data in that table. If there is a row in that table that contains a file that *doesn't* start with {filedir_1} (or {filedir_2} etc.) you have a problem. Delete or fix any row that has a filename without {filedir_1}.

Then, if you have an newer version of Assets, you'll have the exp_assets_files table instead. If there are any entries in this that has folder_id NULL those need to be set to any valid folder id (e.g. 1). Or just deleted.